# Rust problem with Clap value_of_lossy function

Tags: rust, clap

I have a structure:

```
pub struct Config {
    files: Vec<String>,
....
}
```

I use Clap library to get parameters from the command line

```
.arg(
            Arg::with_name("files")
                .value_name("FILE")
                .help("Input file(s)")
                .multiple(true)
                .default_value("-"),
        )
```

when I try to assign values to struct:

```
Config {
        files: matches.value_of_lossy("files").unwrap(),
....
```

I got the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:42:16
   |
42 |         files: matches.value_of_lossy("files").unwrap(),
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Vec<String>`, found `Cow<'_, str>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<String>`
                found enum `Cow<'_, str>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `catr` (lib) due to previous error
```

How can I get the string Vector from Clap? I do not understand how to transform a Cow and use it.

Comment: `vec![my_cow.into_owned()]` should do it